# Ubuntu 22.04, cannot use external nvidia GPU to render application, on laptop with integrated + dedicated nvidia GPU

Tags: nvidia, graphics, xorg, 22.04, nvidia-prime

I have a laptop running Ubuntu 22.04 with in it intel HD graphics and a discrete nvidia (Quadro M2000M) card, and I'm trying to use an external GPU setup with it (RTX 3060), however I cannot find how to configure my system to allow selecting the eGPU setup to start apps: using `switcherooctl launch` or `__GLX_VENDOR_LIBRARY_NAME=nvidia __NV_PRIME_RENDER_OFFLOAD=1` to select a different card will always result in the system using the dedicated M2000M instead of the external RTX 3060.

I have tried also using the egpu-switcher tool, but any solution which creates a xorg.conf file in /etc/X11/ will prevent the OS from loading X until said xorg.conf file is deleted.

`lspci |grep VGA` correctly detects the cards

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 530 (rev 06)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107GLM [Quadro M2000M] (rev a2)
0a:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GA106 [GeForce RTX 3060 Lite Hash Rate] (rev a1)
```

`nvidia-smi -l 1` shows the card correctly as well

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 510.73.05    Driver Version: 510.73.05    CUDA Version: 11.6     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Quadro M2000M       Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   44C    P8    N/A /  N/A |    259MiB /  4096MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  NVIDIA GeForce ...  Off  | 00000000:0A:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
|  0%   44C    P8    18W / 170W |      1MiB / 12288MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

similar result with switcherooctl

```
Device: 0
  Name:        Intel® HD Graphics 530
  Default:     yes
  Environment: DRI_PRIME=pci-0000_00_02_0

Device: 1
  Name:        NVIDIA Corporation GM107GLM [Quadro M2000M]
  Default:     no
  Environment: __GLX_VENDOR_LIBRARY_NAME=nvidia __NV_PRIME_RENDER_OFFLOAD=1

Device: 2
  Name:        NVIDIA Corporation GA106 [GeForce RTX 3060 Lite Hash Rate]
  Default:     no
  Environment: __GLX_VENDOR_LIBRARY_NAME=nvidia __NV_PRIME_RENDER_OFFLOAD=1
```

However, running for example `switcherooctl launch -g 2 glxgears` will run the command on the dedicated gpu, not on the external one.

I am also able to successfully use the external card as render device on blender, but I am unable to run any other application with it.

Anybody found a way to configure the system to be able to use the external GPU for running applications?

Comment: Try this one: https://github.com/bauca/graphics-switcher

Comment: I managed to get the gpu recognized in xrandr --listproviders by adding Option “AllowExternalGpus” “true” in /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-nvidia.conf as suggested in https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/egpu-issue-how-to-enable-the-external-gpu-to-recognize-the-external-monitor/79917 . I still haven't found a way to run an application with a hand-specified gpu however.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Took me a good amount of time to figure out the solution, which in fact required little to be achieved:

i had to modify /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-nvidia.conf to add

```
Option "AllowExternalGpus" "true"
```

so that it would look like this:

```
Section "OutputClass"
    Identifier "nvidia"
    MatchDriver "nvidia-drm"
    Driver "nvidia"
    Option "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration"
    Option "AllowExternalGpus" "true"
    ModulePath "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/nvidia/xorg"
EndSection
```

After restarting, The device would appear in the nvidia x server settings utility, and in `xrandr --listproviders`:

```
Providers: number : 3
Provider 0: id: 0x42 cap: 0x9, Source Output, Sink Offload crtcs: 3 outputs: 1 associated providers: 2 name:modesetting
Provider 1: id: 0x41f cap: 0x2, Sink Output crtcs: 4 outputs: 7 associated providers: 1 name:NVIDIA-G1
Provider 2: id: 0x29d cap: 0x2, Sink Output crtcs: 4 outputs: 6 associated providers: 1 name:NVIDIA-G0
```

While switcherooctl still doesn't work for specifying the gpu, doing it manually works, by specifying the offload provider:

```
__NV_PRIME_RENDER_OFFLOAD=1 __NV_PRIME_RENDER_OFFLOAD_PROVIDER=NVIDIA-G1 __GLX_VENDOR_LIBRARY_NAME=nvidia glxgears
```

...where NVIDIA-G1 gets replaced by the name of the GPU you wish to use.

Hopefully this will turn out being useful to future egpu information scavengers.